# Dot (.) instead of Swipe tab

Tags: android, android-actionbar

i am implementing view pager and i want to put `dot(.)` in the bottom  instead of swipe tab. how can i do that.Thanks for help

#### Instead of  this

[image]

#### i want to do like this

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Jake Wharton](https://github.com/JakeWharton/Android-ViewPagerIndicator) provides a lot of examples. Have you check it?

And you can take a preview installing this [APK](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.viewpagerindicator.sample&hl=es).

Comment: You have to import this Library into your eclipse. Follow this steps[http://blog.nikhilbaliga.com/2012/12/android-setting-up-viewpagerindicator.html](http://blog.nikhilbaliga.com/2012/12/android-setting-up-viewpagerindicator.html)

Answer (score 3):

Stinepike's answer is more appropriate for tabs. 
But I think what you are trying to achieve can be done by **ViewPager** and Its more appropriate way considering you don't want to display the names of tabs like "tab1", "tab2" etc...  but only the indicators (dots, .)  In that case use [viewpagerindicator](http://viewpagerindicator.com/) with `ViewPager`. 
Using tabs names and indicator will be an overhead and not a proper design for an Android application. 
Its an open source library
Follow the instructions from  this page 
https://github.com/JakeWharton/Android-ViewPagerIndicator/

Comment: yea you are right thats waht i want to implement. white screen at the center ho can i do that? http://viewpagerindicator.com/

Comment: An edit has  been made. Check that.

Comment: Don't forget to accept the answer or do a +1 if it helped

Comment: should i have to import the library for that??