# How to implement a "News like" HorizontalScrollView in Android?

Tags: android, android-listview, android-adapter, horizontalscrollview, horizontallist

I want to implement an Horizontal ScrollView for dinamically show a News section like above:

[image]

The list will be populated dinamically via JSON async request. A simple position indicator (the circles) helps users to navigate trough the news.

I cannot use ViewPager, because the scroll will be a small section of a single activity.

How can I implement it (also using adapters)?

Comment: There are lot of examples online..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20586619/android-viewpager-with-bottom-dots  
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20866201/dot-instead-of-swipe-tab

Comment: use viewpager with pagerIndicator instead of HorizontalScrollView

Comment: Yes, examples about ViewPager but i don't know how to apply them to an HorizzontalScrollView...

Comment: Survivor, I can't because i need a news section INSIDE A PAGE. That's the problem... Below the ScrollView i've got some fixed content. I need to scroll ONLY a small section in the page...

Comment: Adapters are made to populate lists if you want horizontal scroll, then you could rotate a listview, or just MAKE IT, whats the problem? just put the scrollview and fill it with your news.

Comment: The problem? Bottom Dots indicators!

Comment: Check this [link](http://androhub.com/android-image-slider-using-viewpager/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the below library, You can implement dynamically us you can implement in ListView  :

https://github.com/ongakuer/CircleIndicator

Comment: Thank you Mayur!!! I'll try the library. It sounds like just what I'm looking for!!!!